# Postgres on-to-many return parent with count of childs

Tags: postgresql, knex.js, pg

I have a table with users and a table with posts. (users) one to many (posts) and posts has the column user_id referenced to users.id. How to query all users and return all users with count of posts for each users?
ps: I'm also using knex.js query builder

Answer (score 0):

SELECT users.id,count(posts.id) FROM users JOIN posts ON users.id=posts.user_id GROUP BY users.id

knex.select('users.id', knex.raw('count(posts.id)')).from('users').join('posts', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id').groupByRaw('users.id')

PS : use LEFT JOIN rather than JOIN to see also users with no post

Comment: Thanks, It is almost what I'm looking for. This shows all records only for users that have posts. Idk I think it must union this somehow.

Comment: Yes use LEFT JOIN rather than JOIN to see also users with no post